# Chrome extension file downloading

Tags: file, google-chrome-extension, download

I am busy with a chrome extension to download files from a page and saving it to a subfolder with the sitename and the page topic name.

This works fine for files directly linked i.e. ***object.stl***

However, it does not work for files indirectly linked i.e. ***sitename.com/download:12345***

These files only work when you right-click on the links and select ***save link as***

How can tell ***chrome.downloads.download*** to download these indirect file links?

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer. It does in fact download the file(s) BUT I was using the "filename" from the URL (in this case ***download:12345***) as my destination filename which is the invalid part.